# Parse HTML stored in DB

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

{{body}} is a string of HTML. How do I get Blaze to parse the HTML as it's rendering and continue to reactively parse the HTML as the body data changes?

```
{{#each entries}}
    <div class="entry-body">{{body}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the triple bracket syntax :

```
{{#each entries}}
    <div class="entry-body">{{{body}}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Standard disclaimer: don't do this if the `{{body}}` HTML strings are submitted by general users (without using some sort of element/attribute whitelist).